# Disabling an input text when a button is pressed in ADF mobile

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

In an ADF mobile application I want to disable an input-text when a button is pressed. How to do it ? 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a managed bean property to be used for inputText readOnly

```
private boolean readOnlyText = false;
```

Right click on the managed bean class and choose Generate Accessors from the menu. Select readOnlyText to genearate getter/setter methods. Make sure to check

> Notify listeners when property change

check box as this will add PropertyChangeSupport to the bean. As a result the setter method will have following code:

```
public void setReadOnlyText(boolean readOnlyText) {
    boolean oldReadOnlyText = this.readOnlyText;
    this.readOnlyText = readOnlyText;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("readOnlyText", oldReadOnlyText, readOnlyText);
}
```

Use this property in your inputText:

```
<amx:inputText label="label1" id="it1" readOnly="#{viewScope.mBean.readOnlyText}"/>
```

Bound the ActionListener of the button to a method in managed bean:

```
<amx:commandButton text="Disable" id="cb3" actionListener="#{viewScope.mBean.buttonActionListener}"/>
```

In buttonActionListener set readOnlyText = true;

```
public void hideInputActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    setReadOnlyText(true);       
}
```

For more details refer [OTN Code Corner](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/m02-dynamicallyshowhidecomponents-1915399.pdf)

Comment: Tx a lot amishra it worked .. but can you please tell me if I can same method but in bindings way ?